# Android: App stops working after requesting location updates in android simulator

Tags: android, location, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-3.0-honeycomb

My app stopped working after requesting location updates in android emulator. This happens only for android versions over 3.0. 
Any code like the following

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

the app stops working. Is this a regular behavior in simulator for these versions or am I doing something wrong?

More info: If I launch the simulator for android 2.3 or less, the exceptions are being caught properly. This is not happening in the other versions.

```
 12-27 19:17:59.183: W/dalvikvm(640): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at com.rahul.places.AddNewLocation.getUrlArray(AddNewLocation.java:147)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at com.rahul.places.AddNewLocation.access$6(AddNewLocation.java:139)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at com.rahul.places.AddNewLocation$2.onClick(AddNewLocation.java:69)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 12-27 19:17:59.253: E/AndroidRuntime(640):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please check the log cat

Comment: According to the logcat, you are networking on the main thread, you have to do it on a background thread. What code are you calling on line 147 in AddNewLocation.java?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Android is much more strict in dealing with work on the UI thread in more recent versions.

The solution is to use a [handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to change the UI on the UI thread when location updates are available (that is in your onLocationChanged() method).